# Haskell Type Signatures

Tags: haskell, types

I am new to haskell and I read some stuff about this thing called type signatures, but there are a few things that I dont understand.

Here is the the code am looking at:

```
--mult applies product
mult :: Num a => [a] -> a
mult  = foldr (*) 1 

--posList filters positive numbers out
posList :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [a]
posList = filter (>0) 

--trueList determines whether all of the members of a list are T or not
trueList :: [Bool] -> Bool
trueList  =  foldr(&&) True 

--evenList determines where all of the members of a list are even or not
evenList :: (Integral a, Foldable t) => t a -> Bool
evenList x = if (((foldr (+) 2 x ) `mod` 2) == 0) then True else False
```

So, I know you can do those functions easier in a different way, but I had assignments to use higher order functions `map`, `filter` and `foldr`, so I had to do them that way. Anyway, I understand how the functions work since I am the one who wrote them , what I dont understand is those terms `Integral`, `Foldable`, what do they mean? and what are they called in terms of Haskell?

Comment: Did you test `evenList`? I'd suggest you try `evenList [1,3]`.

Comment: Integral and Foldable are *type classes*, google this term. Basically `Foldable t` means "t is a list-like type".

Comment: Type classes are how overloading is done in Haskell. A type implements a type class by implementing some functions. For example, the type of `(+)` is `Num a => a -> a -> a` so if I define a type `Foo` which I want to be able to add then I need to define `(+) :: Foo -> Foo -> Foo` which I can only do by instantiating the `Num` class with `Foo`

Comment: @chi ahahahha thanks for the heads up I fixed it evenList :: [Int] -> Bool
evenList xs =  foldr (&&) (True) (map (even) xs)

Comment: @MostafaIbrahim Much better ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Those are *constraints to a polymorphic type*.

Haskell, despite being statically typed, makes it very easy to write function that can work with different types, through a system called [parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism). I'll first give all your functions concrete (monomorphic) signatures instead:

```
mult :: [Integer] -> Integer
mult  = foldl' (*) 1  -- foldl' is better for performance/memory than foldr

posList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
posList = filter (>0) 

trueList :: [Bool] -> Bool
trueList  =  foldl' (&&) True

evenList :: [Integer] -> Bool
evenList x = foldl' (+) 2 x `mod` 2 == 0
            -- `if True then True else False` is tautological
```

All of these signatures work (both with the improved implementation and with your original ones).

But they *only* work with lists of `Integer`. That's not always sufficiently general; for instance, it's perfectly reasonable to compute the product of a list of fractional numbers. But with the monomorphic signature, `mult [1.5, 2.4, 20]` does not work: these numbers aren't compatible with `Integer`. You don't want to restrict the function to integers, you just want it to work with any number type and always get a result of the same type as the elements. I.e., you basically want the signature

```
mult :: ∀ a . [a] -> a
```

...to be read "for all types `a`, the function `mult` takes a list whose elements have type `a`, and gives a single `a`-value as the result. The `∀` is implicit in Haskell when you have such type variables, i.e. you could as well make it

```
mult :: [a] -> a
```

That doesn't work yet though, because the function must be able to multiply elements. But that is not possible for *all* types, only for [number types](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num). Hence you add the constraint

```
mult :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

For `posList` it's much the same thing: the signature is essentially

```
posList :: [a] -> [a]
```

but you also need to be able to compare (`Ord`) the elements with `0` (`Num`). Thus the constraint

```
posList :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
```

In case of `evenList`, the numerical operations are [`(+)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-), [`(==)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Eq.html#v:-61--61-) and [`mod`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod). So in principle we need `Num`, `Eq` and `Integral`, but `Integral` has `Num` and `Eq` as *superclasses* anyway, so that alone is sufficient:

```
evenList :: Integral a => [a] -> Bool
```

...which is not the most general form yet, though. You reduce that list with a fold, but lists aren't the only thing that can be folded, for instance you can also fold arrays, maps and `Maybe` values. The type class for all containers that can be folded is called, you won't guess it, [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html). So we end up with

```
evenList :: (Integral a, Foldable t) => t a -> Bool
```

You could apply the same generalisation to `mult` and `trueList`:

```
mult :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a
trueList :: Foldable t => t Bool -> Bool
```